# Player velocity not getting reset immediately

Tags: unity-game-engine, sleep, velocity

I have found what seems to be a bug in my current game. I have a menu where the user can reset their position to their initial spawn point in the game. If the player was moving or jumping when the reset button was pressed their velocity does not get reset immediately. In the code below the initial velocity comes in as expected (indicates movement) and then it gets reset to 0. I have tried removing the debug statements to see if it was an order problem but have not had any luck.

```
    Debug.Log("Initial Velocity: " + GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player").GetComponent<PlayerCharacter.PlayerCharacter>().rb.velocity);
    GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player").GetComponent<PlayerCharacter.PlayerCharacter>().rb.velocity = new Vector2(0,0);
    GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player").GetComponent<PlayerCharacter.PlayerCharacter>().rb.Sleep();
    Debug.Log("Updated Velocity: " + GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player").GetComponent<PlayerCharacter.PlayerCharacter>().rb.velocity);
```

The screen shot below is the output I get when running this operation. Any help would be appreciated!

[image]

Comment: idk if this will help but you could try applying a force in the opposite direction of the velocity.

Comment: So you are saying the velocity are 0 when you print, but the object still moves? Are we talking a lot of movement or just a bit. Physics updates are handled inside the `FixedUpdate` and not the `Update` function, so it might because you are setting it inside `Update()`. Is the position also set in the same place? There is also `angularVelocity` if it is because the object is rotating.

Comment: Yes the object still moves but only slightly. The initial position of the player is set inside of a main function. The code above is inside of my restart function which calls the main function and resets the player position.

Comment: How many "Player" game objects do you have in your scene?

Comment: There is just one player.